# Filter string data based on its string length

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, filter

I like to filter out data whose string length is not equal to 10.

If I try to filter out any row whose column `A`'s or `B`'s string length is not equal to 10, I tried this.

```
df=pd.read_csv('filex.csv')
df.A=df.A.apply(lambda x: x if len(x)== 10 else np.nan)
df.B=df.B.apply(lambda x: x if len(x)== 10 else np.nan)
df=df.dropna(subset=['A','B'], how='any')
```

This works slow, but is working.

However, it sometimes produce error when the data in `A` is not a string but a number (interpreted as a number when `read_csv` read the input file):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I believe there should be more efficient and elegant code instead of this.

---

Based on the answers and comments below, the simplest solution I found are:

```
df=df[df.A.apply(lambda x: len(str(x))==10]
df=df[df.B.apply(lambda x: len(str(x))==10]
```

or

```
df=df[(df.A.apply(lambda x: len(str(x))==10) & (df.B.apply(lambda x: len(str(x))==10)]
```

or

```
df=df[(df.A.astype(str).str.len()==10) & (df.B.astype(str).str.len()==10)]
```

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filex.csv')
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('str')
df['B'] = df['B'].astype('str')
mask = (df['A'].str.len() == 10) & (df['B'].str.len() == 10)
df = df.loc[mask]
print(df)
```

Applied to filex.csv:

```
A,B
123,abc
1234,abcd
1234567890,abcdefghij
```

the code above prints

```
            A           B
2  1234567890  abcdefghij
```

Comment: **`astype('str')`** is the key point.  And for sure, before any column data type change.  For check data types in the dataframe, `print(df.dtypes)` is helpful.

Answer (score 39):

A more Pythonic way of filtering out rows based on given conditions of other columns and their values:

Assuming a `df` of:

```
data = {
    "names": ["Alice", "Zac", "Anna", "O"],
    "cars": ["Civic", "BMW", "Mitsubishi", "Benz"],
    "age": ["1", "4", "2", "0"],
}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df:
  age        cars  names
0   1       Civic  Alice
1   4         BMW    Zac
2   2  Mitsubishi   Anna
3   0        Benz      O
```

Then:

```
df[
    df["names"].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
    & df["cars"].apply(lambda x: "i" in x)
    & df["age"].apply(lambda x: int(x) < 2)
]
```

We will have :

```
  age   cars  names
0   1  Civic  Alice
```

In the conditions above we are looking first at the length of strings, then we check whether a letter `"i"` exists in the strings or not, finally, we check for the value of integers in the first column.

Answer (score 19):

I personally found this way to be the easiest:

```
df['column_name'] = df[df['column_name'].str.len()!=10]
```

Comment: while this seems to be more convenient at first it is slower than using apply, especially on bigger data sets.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query('A.str.len() == 10 & B.str.len() == 10')
```

Answer (score 2):

For string operations such as this, vanilla Python using built-in methods (without lambda) is much faster than `apply()` or `str.len()`.

Building a boolean mask by mapping `len` to each string inside a list comprehension is approx. 40-70% faster than `apply()` and `str.len()` respectively.

For multiple columns, `zip()` allows to evaluate values from different columns concurrently.

```py
col_A_len = map(len, df['A'].astype(str))
col_B_len = map(len, df['B'].astype(str))
m = [a==3 and b==3 for a,b in zip(col_A_len, col_B_len)]
df1 = df[m]
```

For a single column, drop `zip()` and loop over the column and check if the length is equal to 3:

```py
df2 = df[[a==3 for a in map(len, df['A'].astype(str))]]
```

This code can be written a little concisely using the `Series.map()` method (but a little slower than list comprehension due to pandas overhead):

```py
df2 = df[df['A'].astype(str).map(len)==3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If You have numbers in rows, then they will convert as floats.

Convert all the rows to strings after importing from cvs. For better performance split that lambdas into multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `df.apply(len)` . it will give you the result

Answer (score 1):

Filter out values other than length of 10 from column A and B, here i pass lambda expression to map() function. map() function always applies in Series Object.

```
 df = df[df['A'].map(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 10)]
 df = df[df['B'].map(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use applymap to filter all columns you want at once, followed by the *.all()* method to filter only the rows where both columns are True.

```
#The *mask* variable is a dataframe of booleans, giving you True or False for the selected condition
mask = df[['A','B']].applymap(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 10)

#Here you can just use the mask to filter your rows, using the method *.all()* to filter only rows that are all True, but you could also use the *.any()* method for other needs
df = df[mask.all(axis=1)]
```