# Pandas filter string data based on its string length using DataFrame.query

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

The question is very similar to this question [Python: Pandas filter string data based on its string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937362/python-pandas-filter-string-data-based-on-its-string-length), but I want to use `pandas.DataFrame.query`. Let's say we have a `pandas.DataFrame`. I like to filter out the rows where the string length of the column `A` is not equal to 3 using `pandas.DataFrame.query`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['hi', 'hello', 'day', np.nan], 'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})  
df.query('A.str.len() != 3')
```

However, I got the following error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `3` with `"3"` works. I'm using `pandas 0.23.1`.

```
df.query('A.str.len() != "3"')
```

Output:

```
       A  B
0     hi  1
1  hello  2
3    NaN  4
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to remove `np.nan` as 3-character string (`NaN`):

```
df.query('A.astype("str").str.len() != "3"')
```

Output:

```
       A  B
0     hi  1
1  hello  2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As of Pandas 1.4.2, OP's original code works.

Filter out rows where A values have length equal to 3:

```py
df.query('A.str.len() != 3')
```

Filter out NaN values in addition to strings of length 3 (leverage the fact that `NaN != NaN`):

```py
df.query('A.str.len() != 3 and A == A')
```

---

For Python 3.9.7 and Pandas 1.3.4, [gyoza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095035/19123103) is not filtering (it's returning the entire df back). However, converting the result of `str.len()` to `dtype str` works.

```py
df.query('A.str.len().astype("str") != "3"')
```

or if it contains NaN that needs to be filtered out:

```py
df.query('A.astype("str").str.len().astype("str") != "3"')
```