# How to discard names with a single character from data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I remove all 'A's and other data like this from the data frame? and I also want to remove XXXX rows from the data frame.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900. What have you tried? Have you done any research? This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19937362/11301900.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

if you want to delete the column where name is A :

```
df[df['name'].ne('A') & df['year'].ne('XXXX'))]
```

to detect when lenght of string in column name is greater than one.

```
df[df['name'].str.len().gt(1) & df['year'].ne('XXXX')]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove all the lines where in column `name` you have 1-character long string just do:

```py
df = df.drop(df.index[df["name"].str.len().eq(1)], axis=0)
```

Similarly for the `XXXX` rows:

```py
df = df.drop(df.index[df["year"].eq("XXXX")], axis=0)
```

And combined:

```py
df = df.drop(df.index[df["name"].str.len().eq(1) | df["year"].eq("XXXX")],axis=0)
```