# Python Panda query() to filter for rows where string is of certain length

Tags: python, pandas

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937362/python-pandas-filter-string-data-based-on-its-string-length) shows how to filter a panda dataframe for length of strings in a column. I am looking for a solution that implements this using `query()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aa','bbb','aaaaa']})
#df.query("len(A) >2")
```

should drop the first row.

Comment: `df.query('A.str.len() > 2')`?

Comment: try `df.query('A.str.len()>2',engine='python')`

Comment: @anky this works for me. PLease repost as an answer