# how can i shorten this looping over the table time procces

Tags: python, regex, pandas

im looking to sum up the number of words above 8 letters that got written in the 'text' column/
the table has above 500,000 values.
i am not inough familiar with panda.

```
def howmany8(array):  //returns the amount of words above 8 letter
  counter=0;
  for i in range(len(array)):
    if(len(array[i])>8):
      counter+=counter
  return counter 


newdf= df;
newdf.dropna(subset = ['text'])
newdf['wordssum']=newdf['text']

for i in range(len(newdf['text'])):
  newdf['wordssum'][i]= howmany8(re.split("\s",newdf['text'][i]))
print(newdf['words'].sum())
```

Comment: I think this might be useful: [Python: Pandas filter string data based on its string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937362/python-pandas-filter-string-data-based-on-its-string-length)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to treat "words" as non-whitespace char sequences. If that is the case, you can use

```py
df.dropna(subset=['text'], inplace=True)         # Remove NA values
df['wordssum'] = df['text'].str.count(r'\S{8,}') # Count occurrences of 8+ non-whitespace chunks
print(df['wordssum'].sum())                      # Print the sum of 'wordssum' column
```

If you want to count only 8+ *letter* words, that are whole words, you need to use

```py
df['wordssum'] = df['text'].str.count(r'\b[^\W\d_]{8,}\b') # Count occurrences of whole 8+ letter words
```

Or, if you do not care if underscores or digits can be "glued" to letters:

```py
df['wordssum'] = df['text'].str.count(r'[^\W\d_]{8,}') # Count occurrences of 8+ letter chunks
```