# I am trying to pop a list but it is returning a Type Error?

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am trying to create a list of words with 5 characters. I am using this approach

```
word = pd.read_csv('words.csv').values.tolist()
for x in word:
    if len(x) != 5:
        word.pop(x)word = pd.read_csv('words.csv').values.tolist()
for x in word:
    if len(x) != 5:
        word.pop(x)
```

But this set of codes returns this particular error

```
word.pop(x)
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Can someone help me understand the Type Error and Troubleshoot it

Comment: what does words.csv look like?

Comment: We can see from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) that `list.pop` expects an (optional) `int` argument.  The error message indicates that `x` is a `list`, not an `int`.

Comment: do you have an example of words.csv? Which line specifically is giving the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop` is a function to remove the ith element from a list. I guess from your code that x is not an integer. You can check this with `type(x)`. I think you want the `remove` function, which

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a faster method to do this, depending on what your CSV looks like.

A CSV that looks like this:

```
WORD
test
david
hello
```

If you have a csv that looks like the above, you can filter out the non-5 letter words like so:

```
word = pd.read_csv('words.csv')

word = word[word["WORD"].apply(lambda x : len(x) == 5)]
```

will output:

```
david
hello
```

I would recommend checking out this StackOverflow answer: [Filter string data based on its string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937362/filter-string-data-based-on-its-string-length)