# Return row number of matching empty cell in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need the row number of a matching cell that is empty: `Int64Index([], dtype='int64')`. I am receiving an `index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` exception.

Print indices of matching elements:

```
if len(item) < 9:
    print(item)
    print(df[df['column name'] == item].index)
```

Output:

```
nan
1234
abc
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([209], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([325], dtype='int64')
```

Print indice number of matching cells:

```
print(df[df['column name'] == item].index[0])
```

Output, empty indice throws exception:

```
index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Output without blank cell:

```
208
324
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is going on in the original df that you are getting an empty index being returned?

Comment: It looks like when you do `df[df['column name'] == nan]`, that filtering is returning an empty dataframe. That is, nothing in the original dataframe has nan as the value there. Then you are trying to print the a row from an empty dataframe, there is nothing to print. You probably want to 1) check if you should be getting nothing from the filter, and/or 2) add a `try:...except:...` for when the filter returns nothing at all

Comment: The nan is an empty cell. That is why the index object contains an empty []. I need the index[0] (row number) of that empty cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get row number(s) of empty cells in column:

```
empty_cells  = df[df[column].isna()]
```

Get row numbers of matching cells, whether empty or not. [Credit to this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937362/filter-string-data-based-on-its-string-length).

```
all_matches = df[df[column].astype(str).map(len) != 9]
```